# Is there a universal way to get a nice textual representation of a variable in VBA?

Tags: vba

In VBA, is there a nice way to get a textual representation of a variable / object?  Like Java's various String.valueOf(...) methods.

Comment: I can't help you with the object representation, but if you just want to display text with proper capitalization, try "StrConv(YourField,vbProperCase)" (This is from Acess VBA)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing built in beyond 'CStr', which has the limitations you've noticed. The only thing you can do is write your own. Luckily, VBA has enough built-in operators ('IsArray', IsNumeric','VarType', etc.) to make it easy. (And that does make you wonder, "why not just make 'CStr' more powerful?"...)

The functions below are an example. They're for Excel/VBA code, so you probably don't care about the implementations of the routines called within them to format arrays, etc., but they should give you the basic idea.

```
'Diagnostic formatting of variant as string
Public Function fmt(arg) As String
    If IsObject(arg) Then
        fmt = fmtObj_(arg)
    ElseIf IsArray(arg) Then
        fmt = fmtArr_(arg)

    'Note that this test must come after IsArray() since IsMissing() returns
    'True for an empty array parameter (created by calling Array())
    ElseIf IsMissing(arg) Then
        fmt = "<Missing>"
    Else
        Select Case VarType(arg)
            Case vbDouble

                'Since we're in Excel, don't include double type char (#)
                fmt = CStr(arg)
            Case vbString
                fmt = """" & arg & """"
            Case vbEmpty
                fmt = "<Empty>"
            Case vbBoolean, vbDate
                fmt = CStr(arg)
            Case vbError
                fmt = fmtExcelVBAError_(arg)
            Case vbLong
                fmt = CStr(arg) & "&"
            Case vbInteger
                fmt = CStr(arg) & "%"
            Case vbCurrency
                fmt = CStr(arg) & "@"
            Case vbNull
                fmt = "<Null>"
            Case Else
                fmt = "<Typename - " & TypeName(arg) & ">"
        End Select
    End If

    If Len(fmt) > MAX_FMT_LEN_ Then
        fmt = Left$(fmt, MAX_FMT_LEN_) & " <...>"
    End If
End Function


'As fmt(), but "normal" conversion for strings, numbers, and Empty
Public Function toStr(arg) As String
    If IsObject(arg) Then
        toStr = fmt(arg)
    Else
        If VarType(arg) = vbString Or VarType(arg) = vbEmpty Or IsNumeric(arg) Then
            toStr = CStr(arg)
        Else
            toStr = fmt(arg)
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try: `CStr(...)`?

Comment: Hmmm, that seems to have problems with Null -- any idea why?

Comment: I think CStr() is the best that VBA has to offer.  Depending on what you want to use it for, TypeName() may also be useful.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to display integers as hexadecimal, octal or binary, this code works in Excel -

```
fmt = CStr(arg) & " - vbInteger" & " - &H" & Hex(arg) & " - &O" & Oct(arg) & " - &B" & WorksheetFunction.Dec2Bin(arg, 8)
```

The output looks like this

**65 - vbInteger - &H41 - &O101 - &B01000001**

If you are not using Excel try this site -

http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_net_dec_hex_oct_bin.html

the function LongToBinary returns a binary text representation of a value.