# What are possible suffixes after variable name in VBA?

Tags: vba

As I've already figured out, there is at least six of them: `!@#$%&`.

Here is snip:

```
Dim A!, B@, C#, D$, E%, F&
Debug.Print "A! - " & TypeName(A)
Debug.Print "B@ - " & TypeName(B)
Debug.Print "C# - " & TypeName(C)
Debug.Print "D$ - " & TypeName(D)
Debug.Print "E% - " & TypeName(E)
Debug.Print "F& - " & TypeName(F)
```

Outputs

```
A! - Single
B@ - Currency
C# - Double
D$ - String
E% - Integer
F& - Long
```

Where is documentation on this syntax sugar?

What other possible suffixes are there?

Is there one for Date?

Comment: Run away! Run away! Run away some more! These are awful, horrible leftovers that shouldn't be used, period. The closest I ever come is that I use `Right$`, `Left$`, `Mid$` and `Trim$` to force the return of strings rather than the Variant returned by the versions without `$`,

Comment: @Roland, agreed! I use them for exactly one purpose: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047239/is-there-a-universal-way-to-get-a-nice-textual-representation-of-a-variable-in-vb/3047931#3047931

Comment: Agree with Roland, but still +1 for the question and the term _syntax sugar_ It's like code giving you a kiss.  (Yes, I'm lonely.)

Comment: There are only 6 [Type Characters (Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9cz43ek)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A full(?) list is here http://support.microsoft.com/kb/110264 under Variable and Function Name Prefixes. As Remou said - they are not recommended (the article says that use is "discouraged"). I believe you covered them all in your list. Date is technically a variant (stored as a floating point) so no shortcut for that one.

Comment: broken link, couldnt find new one

Comment: The linked page is archived at https://web.archive.org/web/20110116055510/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/110264 .

Answer (score 13):

These suffixes are *type hints*, and the link in the accepted answer is outdated.

```
Dim someInteger% '% Equivalent to "As Integer"
Dim someLong&    '& Equivalent to "As Long"
Dim someDecimal@ '@ Equivalent to "As Currency"
Dim someSingle!  '! Equivalent to "As Single"
Dim someDouble#  '# Equivalent to "As Double"
Dim someString$  '$ Equivalent to "As String"

Dim someLongLong^  '^ Equivalent to "As LongLong" in 64-bit VBA hosts
```

So you had them all, except `^` for `LongLong`, introduced in VBA7 for 64-bit host applications. Exactly why Microsoft introduced a new type hint for a new value type is beyond me though.

It's more *syntax poison* than *syntax sugar* though, and dates all the way back from ancestral, dinosaurian versions of BASIC before the `As` clause was a thing, for example in this Commodore 64 BASIC 2.0 fizzbuzz code:

```
1000 REM INIT VARIABLES
1010 LET FIZZ$ = "FIZZ"
1011 LET BUZZ$ = "BUZZ"
1020 LET FIZZ% = 3
1021 LET BUZZ% = 5
1030 LET MIN% = 1
1031 LET MAX% = 15
1100 PRINT FIZZ$ + ":" + STR$(FIZZ%)
1101 PRINT BUZZ$ + ":" + STR$(BUZZ%)
1102 PRINT FIZZ$ + BUZZ$ + ":" + STR$(FIZZ%*BUZZ%)
1105 PRINT
```

As you can see, type hints aren't the only paleo-code that VBA supports: line numbers, `Rem` comments, and explicit `Let` value assigments were also a thing in 1982. Avoid them at all costs.

In literals, prefer explicit conversions over type hints:

```
Debug.Print TypeName(32&) 'prints Long
Debug.Print TypeName(CLng(32)) 'prints Long
```

> *Ask yourself not whether you **can**, ask yourself whether you **should**.* -- unknown

Answer (score 3):

These are long since deprecated and only remain for backward compatibility AFAIK. Declare your variables as the type required. You can also coerce variables to type.

Comment: It's pretty handy, you know :). IMHO VB itself is a huge backward compatibility and no one should ever write a program on it, however, things are a little bit different in the tough reality.Have you any reference for me, so I can look it up and decide whether to use it or not?

Comment: I script things daily in VBA. 'twould be nice to move to VB.Net, but this isn't a tech company and we probably won't upgrade to a newer version of Office until we absolutely have to. (This doesn't really answer your question.  I just felt like saying it).

Comment: You can get it from the VB6 information http://www.thevbprogrammer.com/Ch02/02-02-DataTypesNamingConv.htm. Note that not all types are available, which would be a major reason to avoid this notation, quite apart from clarity. All data types are available with intellisense and the use of `As`.

Comment: @PowerUser It is amazing how often people who criticize VBA forget that it is extremely useful for small companies with no in-house IT and no budget for buying in IT. VBA is a great deal better than repetitive manual work, and a great deal better than nothing at all.