# What is the default return type for functions in VBA?

Tags: function, vba, return-type

Just realised I did't know the answer to this and neither was there a question on SO, so here it goes:

What is the default return type for `Function` routines in VBA when none is specified?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a type is not specified explicitly then `Variant` is the default.

<sub>Technically speaking it's a `0` which is in turn a `vbEmpty` but let's not go into any further details for this simple question. `Variant` may change its type depending on the value being returned(if any). See [**this** interesting post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21386768/why-am-i-having-issues-assigning-a-range-to-an-array-of-variants)</sub>

Comment: Not always true, see my post

Comment: @z always true :) Think of it like this `Variant` in VBA is a bit like `Object` in .Net :)

Comment: I know what a `Variant` is, but the default return type is not a `Variant` when Using the `Def*` keyword. try running this code: `DefInt I

Sub Itest()
    Itest = "abc"
End Sub

Sub test()
    Itest
End Sub
`

Comment: @z but that's **explicitly** instructing the compiler to treat ITest as Integer.

Comment: No its about changing the default return type of a specific set of functions, which I believe address the question

Comment: @z̫͋ I have brought this to [MSO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/263089/is-my-answer-twisted-in-a-way-that-people-misunderstand-it) for some clarity, just in case you wondered.

Answer (score 8):

According the the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff520659.aspx), the default return type is a `Variant`,
**except** in the following case :

```
DefInt I

' Now Itest will be Integer by default
Function Itest
End Function

Sub Test
    Debug.Print TypeName(Itest) 'will print "Integer", remove the 1st line and you will get "Empty"
End Sub
```

That's right, `DefInt I` says that all names which starts with `I` are Integer by default.

you could also use `DefBool`, `DefByte`, `DefCur`,  `DefDate`, `DefDbl`, `DefInt`, `DefLng`, `DefLngLng`, `DefLngPtr`, `DefObj`, `DefSng`, `DefStr`, `DefVar`

you can even declare ranges:

`DefBool A-C`

[Source](http://www.bettersolutions.com/vba/VAX123/LY710811611.htm)

---

### Edit:

Some names with special suffixes will also behave differently:

```
Function a$()
End Function

Function b!()
End Function

Function c#()
End Function

Function d@()
End Function

Function e%()
End Function

Function f&()
End Function

Sub test()
    Debug.Print "a$ : " & TypeName(a$) ' String
    Debug.Print "b! : " & TypeName(b!) ' Single
    Debug.Print "c# : " & TypeName(c#) ' Double
    Debug.Print "d@ : " & TypeName(d@) ' Currency
    Debug.Print "e% : " & TypeName(e%) ' Integer
    Debug.Print "f& : " & TypeName(f&) ' Long
End Sub
```

For `LongLong` there is also `^` but only for 64-bit implementations

[Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee199603.aspx)
[Related topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4958189/what-are-possible-suffixes-after-variable-name-in-vba)

Comment: **except** that the default is `DefVar A-Z` and therefore any further modifications would be IMHO considered **explicit** which excludes the word "*default*" from the question.

Comment: @mehow The way I understand the question, _default_ is when no type is given in the function definition. I just felt it was worth mentioning this corner case. And for what it's worth, I did not downvote your answer