# Execute multiple commands in Excel Macro By Changing One Number

Tags: excel, vba

Context: I have 10 text boxes (ID1 To ID10) in a user form. The userform will also have a clear button, which will allow the user to clear all the values previously entered in the text box. For that I have inserted the below mentioned command in the Clear Button.

I have multiple commands with the same nomenclature except the number which varies with every text box. I wish to enter one command which will change number and execute all the commands.

Simple example given below: I wish to only put one command instead of the folloing:

```
Private Sub btnClear_Click()

'Empty ID1
ID1.Value = ""

'Empty ID2
ID2.Value = ""

'Empty ID3
ID3.Value = ""
```

.
.
. and so on till
.

```
'Empty ID10
ID10.Value = ""

End Sub
```

I know there is a solution to this, but since I am new cannot find on google using the correct key words. Sorry if this already exists. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What object type are `ID1`, `ID2`, `ID3`, and `ID4`?

Comment: @YowE3K - They are text boxes, I have refined my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If these are TextBoxes on a UserForm, you will be able to do the following from a macro in the UserForm's code module:

```
Private Sub btnClear_Click()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 10
        Me.Controls("ID" & i).Value = ""
    Next 
End Sub
```

It's not possible to dynamically generate a variable and/or object name but, because the `Controls` collection can be indexed by the "name" of the control, it gives an alternative way of getting at the objects.

---

Adding in code for "option boxes" (OptionButtons? `CheckBoxes?) mentioned in comments, and changing the TextBox names to end with a "C":

```
Private Sub btnClear_Click()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 10
        Me.Controls("ID" & i & "C").Value = ""
        Me.Controls("OB" & i).Value = False
    Next 
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Also, if I want to unselect option boxes when I press clear, what command to use then. Option Boxes are OB1,OB2, OB3....OB10.

Comment: @Kaustav - answer edited to include code for "option boxes".

Comment: Okay, I got the option boxes too. But one more doubt. What if the name of my text box is ID1C, ID2C, ID3C. Its not working then. Me.Controls("ID" & i&"C")....is not working.

Comment: @Kaustav - The value being passed as the index of the collection is a string, which can be created in whatever way you need.  If you need `ID1C`, `ID2C`, etc, then you can create a string of `"ID" & i & "C"`.  Just saw the edit to your comment `Me.Controls("ID" & i&"C")` won't work because you don't have a space between `i` and `&`, which makes the compiler think you are trying to use the variable `i&`.  (See http://stackoverflow.com/q/4958189/6535336 for what a variable `i&` means.)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
For i=1 to 4
    str="ID" & i & ".Value = ''"
    Evaluate(str)
Next
```

Comment: (a) you don't need the brackets around `str` in the syntax you have used - you aren't getting `Evaluate` to return a value (b) If you change it to return a value from `Evaluate` (e.g. `x = Evaluate(str)`) the return value will be an error condition because `"ID1.Value = ''"` is not a valid formula. (c) If it was a valid formula, it would be testing whether the left-hand side was `=` to the right-hand side, thus returning a logical value - it wouldn't be executing an assignment statement.

Comment: My mistake I thought it worked the same as MS Access Eval. Been a while since i used it.

Comment: `Evaluate` and `Eval` work very similarly - neither give access to variables/objects within VBA - so you can't use them to perform assignments, or even to say something like `y = 5: x=Eval("y*6")`

Comment: @YowE3K, - It says arguement not possible. Also i have refined my question, if that helps you understand my question better. Thank you.

Comment: @ClintB - It says arguement not possible. Also i have refined my question, if that helps you understand my question better. Thank you.

Comment: @YowE3K - Thanks so much. Also, if I want to unselect option boxes when I press clear, what command to use then. Option Boxes are OB1,OB2, OB3....OB10.