# How to consolidate based on current worksheet path

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to figure out how to consolidate current worksheet.  It would be impossible for me to list everything I've tried but I'll break it down as best I can.

Macro Recorder recorded this when consolidating:

```
Range("G1").Select
    Selection.Consolidate Sources:= _
        "'C:\Users\sognibene\Desktop\[Current needs 9-19-2019 working.xlsx]PO'!C1:C2" _
        , Function:=xlSum, TopRow:=True, LeftColumn:=True, CreateLinks:=False
```

This works if I'm using the workbook called "Current needs 9-19-2019 working.xlsx", but won't work when I change workbooks or worksheets.  I need the code to work on what ever workbook and preferably the worksheet I'm currently on.

I've tried this:

```
Range("G1").Select
    Selection.Consolidate Sources:= _
        "'C:\Users\sognibene\Desktop\" & "["&ActiveWorkbook.Name&"]" & "PO'!C1:C2" _
        , Function:=xlSum, TopRow:=True, LeftColumn:=True, CreateLinks:=False
```

That didn't work.  I've tried it like this:

```
Range("G1").Select
    Selection.Consolidate Sources:= _
        "'C:\Users\sognibene\Desktop\" &ActiveWorkbook.Name& "PO'!C1:C2" _
        , Function:=xlSum, TopRow:=True, LeftColumn:=True, CreateLinks:=False
```

And I've tried a hundred other things. I've tried using ActiveSheet, ActiveWorkbook, and what ever else I could think of.

Answer (score 3):

One must put spaces around the `&` in vba.

This worked:

```
 Range("G1").Select
    Selection.Consolidate Sources:= _
        "'C:\Users\sognibene\Desktop\" & "[" & ActiveWorkbook.Name & "]" & "PO'!C1:C2" _
        , Function:=xlSum, TopRow:=True, LeftColumn:=True, CreateLinks:=False
```

Comment: Note that this is because the `&` in `foo&` gets parsed as a [type hint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41044332/1188513) for a `Long`. With the space, `&` is the string-concatenation operator. Also note that [VB.NET also supports them](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/type-characters), so this isn't just "in VBA".