# Excel crashing when putting value from cell into dimension

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook which creates a new file from template. At one particular step I need a "Channel Count" which is held in formula on the settings sheet of the creator.

This is the code that crashes Excel:

```
Dim ChCount%
ChCount% = Sheet3.Cells(11, 8).Value
```

Annoyingly, this works (but obviously not in the long run as this number is dynamic):

```
Dim ChCount%
'ChCount% = Sheet3.Cells(11, 8).Value
ChCount% = 2
```

Even more annoyingly, this is only affecting the "24h" version of my tool. I have a "standard" version using the *exact* same code and it's still working normally. I have no idea what is going on... Excel just full hard crashes, no error codes, and resets with a bunch of "Repaired" files.

Edit: In case it helps this is the formula in the targeted cell... it simply counts Yes or No how many channels out of 8 max it can have. In this example it should be returning "2":

```
=IF(LEN(H3)>0,1,0)+IF(LEN(H4)>0,1,0)+IF(LEN(H5)>0,1,0)+IF(LEN(H6)>0,1,0)+IF(LEN(H7)>0,1,0)+IF(LEN(H8)>0,1,0)+IF(LEN(H9)>0,1,0)+IF(LEN(H10)>0,1,0)
```

I know that formula isn't "great" but it's been working fine for literally years...

Comment: What is the formula in the cell you get the value from?

Comment: Is this hard crash reproducible in a separate workbook containing only the minimum code and worksheet cell value?  If you read the cell value into a Variant does it crash?

Comment: Thanks for help everyone. I added the formula to OP, also accidentally solved issue with wild theory that the Integer was messed up, so Rounding my formula helped. I cannot reproduce the error on my OTHER tool which uses identical code. I have no idea what the difference is.

Comment: Do you know that your entire formual can be reduced to `=COUNTA(H3:H10)`

Comment: BTW, does Excel crash when you use `ChCount = Sheet3.Cells(11, 8).Value` instead of `ChCount% = Sheet3.Cells(11, 8).Value`?

Comment: Well I have the ChCount dimmed with %, no "as integer"

Comment: You already did it with `Dim ChCount%` so why `ChCount% =` again?

Comment: When I learned of the dim codes I was taught Excel needs the code if you use the code

Comment: @AngryCoder, someone taught you incorrectly then. Also, maybe personal preference, but I find `Dim ChCount As Integer` a lot easier to work with. Also, [run away, run away](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4958189/what-are-possible-suffixes-after-variable-name-in-vba#comment5536182_4958189) from type hints.

Comment: I'll try soon when I can get back to it. The workbook has DB connections so it takes 3-5 minutes to load and test again every time it crashes.

Comment: =COUNTA() worked well to replace the formula, and switching to "as Integer" has let me run without crashing. You can make that an answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is unbelievable but I just Rounded the formula and now it is working. I have a headache. What could have changed overnight? Why does the other tool *without* rounding still work? Inconsistencies aaaaahhhhh!!!!!!!

```
=ROUND(IF(LEN(H3)>0,1,0)+IF(LEN(H4)>0,1,0)+IF(LEN(H5)>0,1,0)+IF(LEN(H6)>0,1,0)+IF(LEN(H7)>0,1,0)+IF(LEN(H8)>0,1,0)+IF(LEN(H9)>0,1,0)+IF(LEN(H10)>0,1,0),0)
```

EDIT: Guess I'm wrong, it's crashing again UGH

My supervisor needs me to work on other stuff for now, I have to step away for awhile. :(

Comment: This formula can be [simplified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73964324/excel-crashing-when-putting-value-from-cell-into-dimension#comment130597681_73964324) (drastically) btw.