Source data not being copied to template
I am running a macro (that I found online) that loops through data in Column C (C2:C100) in my source sheet, named "Data". For each value found in column C (unique values), a new worksheet is being created. The copying and pasting of data is spot on. I am trying to paste the data in another sheet called "Template" in Column C (C14:C100). This is where I am struggling. I'm not sure how and where to reference my Template. In addition to this, I would also like autonumber the newly pasted data on my destination sheet (Template) in column C, after the data has been copied. How do I do this?
Here is the code I've tried.
Sub MakeSheets()
Dim lr As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
Dim ar As Variant
Dim j As Long
Dim rng As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set ws = Sheet3 'Sheets code name
lr = ws.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = ws.Range("C1:C" & lr)
j = ws.[C1].CurrentRegion.Columns.Count + 1

rng.AdvancedFilter 2, , ws.Cells(1, j), True
ar = ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, j), ws.Cells(Rows.Count, j).End(xlUp))
ws.Columns(j).Clear
    
For i = 1 To UBound(ar)
rng.AutoFilter 1, ar(i, 1)
If Not Evaluate("=ISREF('" & ar(i, 1) & "'!C1)") Then
Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = ar(i, 1)
Else
Sheets(ar(i, 1)).Move After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
End If
ws.Range("C2:C" & lr).Resize(, j - 1).Copy [D14] 'Sheets("Template").Range("C14")
Next
ws.AutoFilterMode = False

Sheets("Template").Activate
Range("A1").Activate

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

I would really like some guidance, as I am struggling with this. This is what the source sheet looks like:
Sheet "Data"

My "Template" sheet

Thanks in advance!

Thanks for your help. At present the edited code does the following

Did you want to copy Sheets("Template") and not just add a blank worksheet?

Yes Tinman. The data copied much be copied onto the template ("Template") as the newly created sheet, and renamed either 1A, 1B, 1C or 1D...

Here is the solution as per the latest comment:
Sub MakeSheets()
  Dim lr As Long, i As Long, sz&, lc&, j&
  Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range, ar As Variant, rngtocopy As Range
  
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  
  Set ws = Sheet3
  lr = ws.[C1].End(xlDown).Row: lc = ws.[C1].End(xlToRight).Column
  Set rng = Range(ws.[C1], ws.Cells(lr, lc))
  
  ar = ws.Range(ws.[A2], ws.[A1].End(xlDown))
  
  For i = 1 To UBound(ar)
    rng.AutoFilter 1, ar(i, 1)
    Set rngtocopy = rng.Columns("B:" & Chr$(62 + lc)).Rows("2:" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    If Not Evaluate("=ISREF('" & ar(i, 1) & "'!C1)") Then
      Sheets("Template").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
      ActiveSheet.Name = ar(i, 1)
    Else
      Sheets(ar(i, 1)).Move After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    End If
    With ActiveSheet
      .Rows("14:1000000").Clear
      rngtocopy.Copy .[D14]
      sz = .[D1000000].End(xlUp).Row - 13
      For j = 1 To sz
        .Cells(j + 13, 3) = j
      Next
    End With
  Next
  ws.AutoFilterMode = False
  
  Sheets("Template").Activate
  Range("A1").Activate
  
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub



Any reason you declare i as Integer and j and Long and then the archaic type hint character for autonumber? IMHO you should a) always use Long and b) never use this horrible type hint notation. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/41044332/7599798

Thanks for the help. I realise I should have explained my problem better. What the code is supposed to do is to loop through the data in column C (on the "Data" sheet), starting from C2. The assigned areas are 1A, 1B, 1C and 1D (as per the "Data" sheet). When the macro runs, it should copy the "Template" sheet, create a new sheet and rename it 1A (or 1B, 1C or 1D), containing all the relevant data associated with that particular area (Columns C:E). Autonum also only numbers the rows up until 4...

@FunThomas 1) The 'i' declaration comes from OP's code. I didn't set myself the task to review OP's code. 2) As per Data type summary/Identifier Type Characters, this feature is neither archaic nor horrible. You can like or don't like this feature on your own.

The new code resulted in a Run-Time error '438'. Object doesn't support this property or method (in this line of code):                                                                                               If sz > 0 Then .[C14].Resize(sz, 1) = WorksheetFunction.Sequence(sz)

Are there any other codes I could perhaps use to achieve what I need?

Hi rotabor, your updated tweaks are actually working!!! I only needed to omit a few lines of code in order for it to work as intended. Thanks a million, you're a star!!!
